# Как поменять язык форматированного datetime в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

столкнулся с проблемой рендеринга языка форматированного datetime в Laravel тоесть по-умолчанию если использовать например  $personal->created_at->format('d B Y') то будет показано формат datetime на Английском но я хотел сделать это на Русском и решил использовать этот код

```
 <h6>Добавлен <?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Russian');
        echo $personal->created_at->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y'); ?></h6>
```

Но во view вместо букв показывает 10 ���� 2018. Я использую UTF-8 в html и utf8mb4_unicode_ci в базе данных

Comment: здесь ответ на ваш вопрос:https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/430